# Is the projection a closed function?

Tags: general-topology

> Show that if $Y$ is compact, then the projection $\pi_{X} : X \times Y \rightarrow X$ is a closed function.

I can't to solve the question above. Indeed, I think that projection is a closed (and opened) function even without Y compact. I'm right?

Comment: You definitely need $Y$ compact. Think about the graph of $y=1/x$ projected onto the first coordinate in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Projection map is always an open map. but for being a closed map $Y$ has to be compact. Take the graph of  $y=1/x$ in first quadrant. It is closed. But its projection onto the $X$- axis is positive reals which is not closed.